# How to show crystal report taken from combination selection formula in vb6

Tags: vb6, report, selection, formula

Please help me... I need to show report taken from combination selection formula between datetime and varchar database field. I use this source :

```
.SelectionFormula = "{sales.date}=#" + Format(datapicker1.Value, "mm-dd-yyyy") + "#" And "{sales.customer} in '" & combo1.Text & "'"
```

But, this source error type mismatch... what's problem? I using vb6, sql server 2000 and crystal report (Version 8.5). Thank you very much... Thanks stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you are using the `And` VB operator with two strings. VB will try to convert the strings

```
"{sales.date}=#22-06-2014#"
```

and

```
"{sales.customer} in 'mycombotext'"
```

into Boolean values. They won't convert - thus the Type Mismatch error. You need the following:

```
.SelectionFormula = "{sales.date}=#" + Format(datapicker1.Value, "mm-dd-yyyy") + "# And {sales.customer} in '" & combo1.Text & "'"
```

Comment: Well, it looks as if you understand strings. It is just that you accidentally terminated your string by adding two extra `"` characters. Note that this would have been caught in other languages at the point where you compiled the code. VB tries to do what you ask, even if it doesn't make a lot of sense. So in this case, it tried to convert the strings into Boolean values.

Comment: that shouldn't terminate the string.  Worst case, and it's something the OP should consider, is it pulls all customers that are null string.  http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt2.html  I recommend using the & operator versus + to avoid type coercion issues.